# How can I display user comments for a Facebook Event or Group on my website?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to integrate user comments for a Facebook or Group on my website. It's simple enough to insert a [Facebook Live Stream widget](http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=258) into a site, but it only shows comments that other users post via the widget on my site.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, but would prefer to use HTML/Javascript integration over server-side integration if possible.

Comment: Note - I'm not talking about web-scraping. Facebook has an API which allows for external integration - e.g. the Live Stream widget I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requested Feature is currently not possible.
I guess there will be something similar possible but only for Pages and Profiles. (See Comments API) For current use i would try to stick to an Page (Public Profile) and use the [Fan Box](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fan_Box)

Answer (score 1):

Try the wallflux of your group, http://wallflux.com/feed/115227675156013, does that serve the need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Facebook permits scraping their content back to your site.